# Add compiler support for c++ 2011

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I try to compile a robot for torcs with the usage of opendavinci. The problem is that everytime i try to compile it

> `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard`

appears. The obvious solution is to add the support, but i have a complicated makefile that is from torcs so i dont know how to work around this problem.

Is there any way to add the support without changing the makefile? I read about the CXXFLAGS that coud help me but i dont understand how it works.

The compiler is g++ 5.4.0 for Ubuntu

```
felix@ubuntufelix:/usr/src/torcs/torcs-1.3.7/src/drivers/bt$ make
g++ -I/usr/src/torcs/torcs-1.3.7/export/include -I/usr/src/torcs/torcs-1.3.7 -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -DUSE_RANDR_EXT -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -Wall -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -DUSE_RANDR_EXT -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES  -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -DSHM -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -c driver.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/array:35:0,
                 from driver.h:15,
                 from driver.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
```

Comment: **What** compiler??

Comment: Made an edit it is g++ 5.4.0

Comment: _"Is there any way to add the support without changing the makefile?"_ Well, what's the rest of the build system? If it uses something like Autoconf or Meson, then you can pass custom compiler/preprocessor/etc. arguments through that. You still need to add more info.

Comment: You can try `CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" make`

Comment: This is a build problem. Show us how you build your binary, we might tell you how to do it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no completely standard way to build distributed software, but there *should* be a `README` or `INSTALL` file in the distribution, which gives more-or-less precise instructions.  Ideally, distributions come with a configure script, and the installation process consists of `./configure; make; make install`, possibly with some per-distribution special options given to `./configure`.  The basic process here is that the `./configure` script edits suitable values into `Makefile.in` to generate `Makefile`, but such scripts can be arbitrarily complicated.  Of course, things are rarely quite that simple, and building complicated software from source can be quite a technical challenge (this is why package managers are a Good Thing).

If there are *no* such installation instructions (have you double-checked?), then you should go back to the software distribution point and ask for help there (you're allowed to have a hint of reproach in your question as you do so – *everyone*, distributing even pre-beta software, should tell users how to build things).

If you've been left high and dry, however, then the following should broadly indicate where to look next:

---

You need to add an option to the invocation of the compiler, to tell it to support C++ 2011 features (I'm pretty sure g++ 5.4 has these features available, but they aren't enabled by default).

You do that by adding the `-std=c++11` option to the compiler flags, and the way you do *that* is using the `CXXFLAGS` makefile variable that you measured (note: `CXXFLAGS` is the probable/conventional name for this variable, but it's not an inviolable rule).

Depending on how the Makefile is structured, you can add or adjust that variable in a number of ways.

- Edit the Makefile – search for `CXXFLAGS` in the Makefile and add that `-std` option to that definition.
- You will be able to redefine the variable on the make command line: `make CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11`, but that will stomp on any definition within the Makefile, which might be important.
- The Makefile might be structured so that the definition includes `CXXFLAGS=-foo -bar $(EXTRA_CXXFLAGS)`, which is there precisely so that you can call make with `make EXTRA_CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11`.
- If there's a `./configure` step to building this software, then there may be an option available to `./configure` when doing that step (that doesn't sound like the case here).

But one way or another, your goal is to get `-std=c++11` appearing in the compiler invocation that's produced by the Makefile.  Note that if you give the `-n` option to `make`, then it will show you what commands it would produce, without actually doing anything.

Have fun.

Comment: I will try your answer and maybe it works but i searched for cxxflags in the makefile and it is only used sometimes but never defined is there a way to make a header File or something for makefiles ? And ./configure is existing i look for that also. Thanks !

Comment: Nice answer to a bad question. `./configure` if built by autoconf has an help option: `./configure --help` might help OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ./configure with CXXFLAGS=-stdc++11 did it for me! The question was shitty but your answer helped me a lot :)!